# How to call class member function from a QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt-creator, qthread

I am trying to create a class, which (if it's possible this way) will be running in a separate thread. All examples that I found are showing a worker thread which exits after it does it's work(in one function):

```
void Worker::doWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        emit updateCount(i);
        qApp->processEvents();
        sleep(1000);
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

In this example, as far as I understand, thread exits after emitting 'finished' signal.
What I am trying to make is this:

- Create a thread;
- Create a worker class object;
- Move object to a thread using moveToThread();
- Then I want the class object to sit in another thread doing nothing until main
  program calls a function from the class.

I threw together this code:

worker.h

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void process();
    void TestFunc();
    void Kill();

signals:
    void finished();
};
```

worker.cpp

```
//constructor{..}
//destructor{..}

void Worker::process() {
    qDebug("Hello World!");
}

void Worker::TestFunc()
{
    int n=0;
    while(n<10)
    {
    qDebug("Hello World from testfunc");
    n++;
    Sleep(1000);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
}

void Worker::Kill()
{
emit finished();
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int eh;
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    thread->start();
    worker->TestFunc();
    scanf("%i",&eh);
    worker->Kill();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The problem is that after I call 'worker->TestFunc()', main thread(console window) is blocked, i.e. I can't type anything until the TestFunc is finished.

I'm sure I am doing this wrong, but I can't figure out the right way of doing this. Please guide me into the right direction.

Comment: You're executing a method from worker class in your main (GUI) thread, that's the reason why it blocks main program.

I suggest you to declare signal in your mainWindow.h, and connect it to  a preferred slot from your worker class instance, it should work. To clear your confusion about threads read https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/.

Comment: Or if you don't want to use a signal, use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).

Comment: Thanks, both solutions worked.